# Approximating e^x to within 0.025 by Taylor polynomial in interval [-1,1]

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation

I want to use $R_{(5)}(x)$ to show that $e^x$ can be approximated by the polynomial $T_{(4)}(x)$ to within $0.025$ for all values of $x$ on the interval $[-1,1]$. I just don't know how to treat the interval.

$$R_{(5)}(x) = e^\xi\frac{x^5}{5!} $$ ( where $\xi$ is between $0$ and $x$)

Using $|x| \le 1$, $|\xi| \le 1$, and $e < 3$

$$R_{(5)}(x) \le  \left\lvert e^\xi\frac{x^5}{5!} \right\rvert \\ 
 = 3\frac{1^5}{5!} \\ 
= 0.025$$

Would this be enough to show what I wanted to show?

Comment: In writing the remainder term $R_{(5)}(x)$ the way you did, you presumably have in mind that the fifth derivative of $e^x$ is again $e^x$, so that evaluating the fifth derivative looks like $e^\xi$ for some $\xi \in [-1,1]$.

Comment: @hardmath Yes, have I done/thought this correctly?

Comment: Sure, I'm just leaving a bit of context for Readers who may be puzzled by where you jumped in to Taylor series with Remainder (as some authors call it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is enough.

The Lagrange Error bound computes the MAXIMUM possible error on the interval, so any real error between the polynomial and the function will be less than or equal to the computed maximum.